How can we run all of our google cloud functions at once using functions framework
Is it possible to run all of our functions at the same time without having to write custom script or wrapping our functions inside express apps.
I would expect something like this:
npx @google-cloud/functions-framework myfolder

But nothing is mentioned in the documentation.
We have a lot of functions so having to write custom scripts we will not use we will stick with firebase emulator instead

the functions are designed to be independent. Wishing running all in the same time does not really make sense on Google perspective. Therefore, it's not possible out of the box. You need a custom script to achieve this.

As usual google thinks what they need not what developers using the technology need. Angular team FTW.  Thanks for the reply

As guillaume blaquiere stated in comment,  it is not possible for now, There is also  a request raised for this at github and a workaround shared by @dupski

Found a simple workaround for this - just define an "index" function
which then calls your other functions for local development, e.g.:
export function index(req: Request, res: Response) {
switch (req.path) {
case '/oauth2_init':
  return oauth2_init(req, res)
case '/oauth2_callback':
  return oauth2_callback(req, res)
case '/my_func':
  return my_func(req, res)
default:
  res.send('function not defined')   } }

and have that as the target when running the function framework
locally, i.e.:
npx @google-cloud/functions-framework --target=index

If the workaround in the github does not answer, you may try adding your concern over there
further progress can be tracked there.

Always hacks with GCP kinda sick of it but thanks it is easier to maintain this than the script
